# Navigating through flutter screens automatically

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, location

I'm developing an app that is using location data. So in the landing screen, I will check whether the permission to access location data is granted or not. I do this using the geolocator package. When the user grants permission, I will collect the data like current location and then I want to automatically move into another screen, which is the main screen of the app. Is there any way that I'm able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your main screen depend on a value or condition I think you could simply use a `Streambuilder` at your home, whose `streamcontroller` receives a boolean, depending on which it'll return one screen or another.

Here for example I used this `Streambuilder` that listens to a boolean. I will change the value of this boolean to true by pressing a button. In my `Streambuilder` at my home I have the condition that, if the info received, the `snapshot.data` is true, then it should not return the MyHomePage but instead TheOtherRoute.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

final StreamController<bool> _streamController =
    StreamController<bool>.broadcast();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _streamController.stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.data == true){
              return TheOtherRoute();
            }
          return MyHomePage();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('this is a testo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: FlatButton(
                color: Colors.black38,
                child: Text('Change boolean'),
                onPressed: () {
                  _streamController.add(true);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Your boolean changed. Your home page is now FirstRoute()'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Try it out and let me know.

Comment: I also thought of that, but I'm not sure how to automatically trigger that function when the condition is fulfilled, would you please explain it a bit more

Comment: Please try to implement this code and let me know if it worked for what you're looking for ;)

Comment: No, this is not what I was looking for. My first screen will anyway be the landing screen. So in that I'm checking whether I have been given the location permission or not. If it's not given then it updates to an error message, but if permission granted it will automatically redirect to the main page. So the home route will be the landing screen anyway. So this doesn't work

Comment: Okay, I get it. If I have more time I'll try to adapt my code and help you out. In the meantime I think, at least in my opinion, that the approach that you should use is a stream that listens to a given condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a simple app to demonstrate the permission checking and proper handling of the navigation based on the outcome. You can check the below code and commentation to understand the flow:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class SomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  void _determinePosition(context) async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;
    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    
    // Checking if the service is enabled
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      // If not, display a Snackbar
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text('Location services are disabled.'),
        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
      ));
    }

    // Checking the permission here
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
        _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text(
              'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.'),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
        ));
      }

      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text('Location permissions are denied'),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
        ));
      }
    }

    // Finally if the permission is granted, navigate the user to new screen
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
    Navigator.push(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home(position: position)));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () => _determinePosition(context),
          child: Text("Check permission"),
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//  A simple screen to display the position
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  final Position position;

  Home({this.position});

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
              'Location: ${widget.position.altitude} ${widget.position.longitude}'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. But unfortunately this will not be suitable for my situation .My situation is if the user has not allowed permission, then I will show a message and it will remain in the same page, and once the user grants location access (or switches on location service if it's switched off) this will navigate to another screen. I was able to work through it, what I did was, I used a timer in initstate which will keep on checking whether the user has allowed location until the user permits, and when the user permits, it will navigate to the required page